# Inner join query in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
**SUB_ID_DTLS:**
================
Sub_Id   Id_Val
================
497     16000123-9
495     16000123-9
489     16000281-7

**SUB_DTLS**
===========
Sub_id   TxnId
=============
499       683
498       682
497       681

**TN_DTLS**
===========
TN           TxnId
==================
9999098766  683
9999098766  682
9999098765  681

**PORT_DTLS**
=============
TxnId     Time
==============
683        04:47.3
682        03:45.4
681        05:21.4
```

Above four tables are my tables. I need TN between system date.

Below is my query.

```
select A.TN,B.TXN_ID,C.ID_VAL,D.SUB_ID 
from TN_DTLS a,PORT_DTLS b,SUB_ID_DTLS c,SUB_DTLS d 
where ((A.TXN_ID=B.TXN_ID) and (B.TXN_ID=d.TXN_ID)) and  (C.SUB_ID=D.SUB_ID) and b.TIME between sysdate - 1 AND sysdate;
```

But I am not getting all TNs between that time. I need TNs which don't have ID_Val.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the database tables such as their structure and the relationships between the tables? Also if you could provide some context about what you are trying to achieve. The way the question is worded at the moment its very difficult to see what the issue is. I'd suggest taking a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In my query, it is fetching tn, id_val based on sub_id and txn_id. My requirement is print all tn,txn_id,id_val from all tables between mentioned time.If data is not in db for particular tn, it should print null val.   Suppose my tns are 9999098766,9999098766,9999098765. For this tns I need txn_id,id_val,sub_id. If any filed is not present it should give null value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `left join`.  Follow a simple rule:  don't use commas in the `from` clause.

```
select A.TN, B.TXN_ID, C.ID_VAL, D.SUB_ID
from TN_DTLS a left join
     PORT_DTLS b
     on A.TXN_ID = B.TXN_ID b.TIME between sysdate - 1 AND sysdate left join
     SUB_DTLS d
     on B.TXN_ID = d.TXN_ID
     SUB_ID_DTLS c
     on C.SUB_ID = D.SUB_ID;
```

This will keep all records in `a`, even when there are not any matches in the other tables.

Comment: It will help for me. I got an Idea.Thanks @Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

select tn,id_value,txn_id,sub_ID from tn_dtls a join port_dtls b on A.TXN_ID=B.TXN_ID left join sub_dtls c on a.TXN_ID=C.TXN_ID left join 
np_sub_id_dtls d on D.SUB_ID=C.SUB_ID where b.TIME between sysdate - 1 AND sysdate;